# jquery mobile error page duration

Tags: popup, jquery-mobile

I'm able to customize an error message by doing this:

```
<script>
    $(document).bind('mobileinit', function () {
        $.mobile.pageLoadErrorMessage = 'Use full version';
    })
</script>
```

But the message disappears too fast.
Is there any way to customize duration of the pop-up messages?

Answer (score 1):

get the un-compressed version of jquery-mobile and modify the code for your needs, then re-compress it back and you will have your custom delay.  I have looked in the config and there seems to be no way to set this.

Comment: I was afraid that I'll hear this :) I looked at source code and see that the duration time is hardcoded to 400ms

Answer (score 0):

setTimeout would be a solution, i guess.